# Local edits and nested datastructures with React + Flux

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native, flux

I have two stores, an `EventStore` and an `InviteStore`, each containing a collection of `Event`s and `Invite`s respectively. `Event`s have a one-to-many relationship with `Invite`s, and my backend returns nested JSON data, but that's not the issue. I simply normalize the data and let it trickle down to both stores via either a `FETCH_EVENTS_LOAD` or `FETCH_INVITES_LOAD` dispatch, so the data is always fresh.

Now here's the issue - I want the user to be able to edit `Event`s locally. This is simple enough when editing simple string/number fields, since I can just pass the `Event` on to the edit component's state, have the textfields update said state, and send the state on to the server once the user has finished editing - easy.

But I also want to be able to append `Invite`s to the `Event`, and since I normalize the data, an `Event`'s `Invite` collection is but a list of IDs. Newly created local `Invite`s don't have IDs, since they haven't been persisted to the server - yet.

So this leaves me with two options, as far as I can tell. I either start inserting `Invite`s into my `InviteStore` before sending them off to the server, which would require me to create unique, local IDs and somehow track these and map them to server responses, or I map the `Event`'s `Invite` ID collection to their actual respective `Invite` objects, i.e. essentially undoing the normalization step, both of which seem equally unappealing.

TL;DR: I want to edit local nested state without persisting it to my backend immediately.

Comment: Can we assume a given invite is only applicable to a single event?

Comment: Yes, a single `Invite` belongs to just one `Event` - sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: How is the data structured server-side? Does an event have a collection of invite IDs, or does an invite have an event ID?

Comment: Both API endpoints preload their respective relations.

Comment: What I'm thinking is do you need to have a list of ids stored in an event, if your invites already store what event they are for?  If you only store the relationship on the invite, not on the event, then you can just add a new invite with the corresponding event ID.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective, maybe I could get it to work. But I would still need a `findForEvent` operation in my `InviteStore` since I save the `Event` resource along with its respective `Invite`s by `PUT`ing to the `/events/` endpoint.

Comment: Why not just make the server aware that if it sees `Invite`s attached to an `Event` without an ID that it needs to create them? Then on success, great, or, on failure, the server just doesn't create anything (rollback the transaction)?

Comment: That's exactly what it does, but this approach requires me to unnormalize the data (i.e. map the collections of IDs to their respective `Invite` objects), which I'm no fan of, since the nesting doesn't stop with `Invite`s.